# Как передавать данные между страницами во фрейме Content в NavigationView?

Tags: c#, uwp

Здравствуйте!

Пробую научиться работать с новым NavigationView.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно передавать данные для изменения между страницами во фрейме Content (который x:Name="ContentFrame") ?

Например:
1-я страница - список пользователей (UsersLst);
2-я страница - как бы форма для редактирования пользователя (User)

Как сделать так, чтобы из первой страницы перейти во вторую, изменить там пользователя (например Имя поправить), и при возвращении на первую страницу - там бы уже был измененённый список пользователей?

Comment: Освойте паттерн MVVM. Задача превращается в тривиальную. На главной VM вы имеете коллекцию UserVM. 1-я страница имеет в качестве DataContext главную VM, при выборе пользователя - создаете экземпляр 2-й страницы и устанавливаете ей в качестве DataContext нужного UserVM. Всё.

Comment: @АндрейNOP, а при таком варианте, когда на второй странице по кнопке сработает GoBack()  - на первой странице отобразятся изменения, сделанные на 2-ой странице в UserVM?

Comment: Конечно отобразятся, ведь обе страницы будут фактически ссылаться на один и тот же объект!

Comment: @АндрейNOP, извините, не получается.
Изменяю UserVM на 2-ой странице, но при возврате на предыдущую страницу - там список показан без изменений. 
В чём может быть причина? Как предыдущая страница с главной VM узнает, что изменился какой-то UserVM ?

Comment: UserVM, как и все другие VM должны реализовать INotifyPropertyChanged чтобы оповещать GUI об изменениях

Comment: @АндрейNOP,  да, я его реализовал вроде... взял с примеров.

Смущает в основной странице код:
public AccountsListViewModel VM = new AccountsListViewModel();
Разве это не означает, что при возврате на первую страницу список будет каждый раз заново создаваться (у меня в конструкторе AccountsListViewModel() - заполняются тестовые данные списка - несколько предопределённых строк)?

Comment: Не, вы должны создавать VM один раз и использовать этот экземпляр всегда, а не каждый раз новый...

Comment: Не совсем понятно, правда как действовать в UWP... Можно попробовать в App.xaml.cs создать экземпляр главной VM и установить его в OnLaunched в rootFrame.DataContext. Также в главной VM создать свойство наподобие `CurrentUser` и устанавливать его при выборе в списке. А на второй странице привязываться уже непосредственно к этому свойству. Как-то так. Я больше по WPF, поэтому в UWP для меня с MVVM не все до конца понятно

Comment: @АндрейNOP, спасибо! Да, всё получается, как Вы сказали, если задать переменную UsersListViewModel в основной стартовой странице MainPage (основная - та, которая содержит в себе NavigationView и его contentFrame). Тогда эта VM становится доступной на всех страницах, которые мы будем открывать в contentFrame.
С одной стороны - это решение проблемы. А с другой - не уверен, что это правильно. Вдруг понадобиться оперировать очень большим списком и хранить его постоянно в памяти ради одной/двух страниц - наверное будет не самым лучшим решением.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для себя сделал такие выводы.

Если на какой-то странице вы создаёте объект, например:

```
public AccountsListViewModel VM = new AccountsListViewModel();
```

То этот объект при навигации на эту страницу - будет каждый раз создаваться заново!
(и при первом "запуске" страницы, и при втором, третьем...., и при возвратах на эту страницу, всегда!)

Потому что страница - это класс. И при навигации на эту страницу каждый раз создаётся новый экземпляр этого класса.
Соответственно все реквизиты класса инициируются заново.

Из-за этого и возникает ошибка, когда на странице создаются демо-данные, потом эти данные передаются в другую страницу, изменяются, но при возврате на первую страницу - изменений в этих данных НЕ БУДЕТ! т.к. при возврате на страницу - эти данные БУДУТ СОЗДАНЫ ЗАНОВО!

**Для решения проблемы**: те данные, которые надо хранить в приложении в целом и передавать между страницами - можно объявлять в классе App. (Например, создавать экземпляр какого-нибудь глобального NavigationView) Тогда они будут доступны на всех страницах и будут хранить сделанные в них изменения.